# django south migration, doesnt set default

Tags: python, django, django-south

I use south to migrate my django models. There is however a nasty bug in south. It doesn't set default values in Postgres Databases. Example:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
tag_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
```

South will add these 2 fields to database, but fail to set their default values, which needs to be done manually.

Is there any patch for this bug?

**UPDATE**
I had already tried setting default date with `auto_now_add=True`, but that is also not setting defaults. Adding `null=True` in field adds a `db.alter_column` in migration script produced by south. But that only *removes `NOT NULL`* constraint, doesnt add a default. Same for integer field

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug, in South or elsewhere.

I think you are confused about how default values work in Django generally. Django does not set default values in the database schema. It applies them directly in Python, when a new instance is created. You can verify this by doing `manage.py sqlall` and see that the generated SQL does not contain `default` attributes.

Comment: How can I enforce a default in Postgres database. I have apis that negotiate directly with database created by django. They expect defaults to be in place.

Comment: You'll have to use custom SQL to modify the schema yourself. You can do this within South by passing the SQL to [`db.execute`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html#db-execute).

Comment: Daniel just because Django tries to prevent users from altering field defaults at the schema level, that doesn't mean that they SHOULDN'T be able to. I have posted an actual solution below.

Comment: Well it strange when you add some not-blank not-null field to model, specify default value and south doesn't use it for existing rows. Looks like South allows to violate constraints.

Answer (score 22):

If you are auto-generating your migrations using:

```
./manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto
```

Then you need to make a small edit to the migration before you actually apply it. Go into the generated migration (should be called something like `app_name/migrations/000X__auto_add_field_foo.py`) and look for the argument:

```
keep_default=False
```

in the `db.add_column` call. Simply change this to:

```
keep_default=True
```

And Django will now apply your default value to the actual schema, in addition to any existing rows. Would be great if South had some kind of setting to generate this parameter as `True` by default, but no such luck. You will need to make this edit every time.

Comment: +1. Unfortunately [`keep_default` is deprecated in South 0.8.1](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/0.8.1.html#keep-default-fully-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in earlier answers, the default mechanism in django is implemented in the model class, and is not relevant to south migrations.

Also, since south 0.8, [the `keep_default` flag is deprecated](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#db-add-column), and won't add the default value to your model.

What I do to solve this is writing a custom migration to add the default value. You can do that by creating a separate [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations):

```
./manage.py datamigration your_app_name migration_name
```

and add the following line to the `forwards` function:

```
orm.YourModel.objects.update(field_name = DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

Alternatively, instead of creating a new migration, you can modify your original migration:

1. add `no_dry_run = True` to the class itself (so you will have access to the ORM).
2. add `orm.YourModel.objects.update(field_name = DEFAULT_VALUE)` to the end of the `forwards` function.

This way you don't have to write a backwards migration, because you already have the original delete-column one.