# django model field: Why default value not working?

Tags: django

When I create a new row in my PG commander
I let `small_price` empty because I thought I set a default : 0

```
small_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

But when I saved It has an alert :

```
Reason: null value in column "small_price" violates not-null constraint
```

Why the default not work??
Do I still need to type 0 when create row??

Comment: It should work without having to specify the type again.. can you clear the pyc file and try again?

Comment: I try,but still not work

Comment: I found the answer in here ! ````http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991708/django-south-migration-doesnt-set-default ````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django south migration, doesnt set default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991708/django-south-migration-doesnt-set-default)

Answer (score 0):

If you are auto-generating your migrations then you need to make a small edit to the migration before you actually apply it. Go into the generated migration and look for the argument: `keep_default=False`
in the db.add_column call.

You have to change it to: `keep_default=True`

This way Django will apply your default value to the actual schema + any existing rows.